# Can I run Ubuntu Gnome without GPU?

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, graphics, overheating

this might seem like a stupid question, but is it possible to run Ubuntu Gnome (or any other desktop environment) only on my Intel CPU? I actually have a Nvidia GPU, but the fan is broken and since it is an XMG it takes forever to deliver a new one. In the meantime I do not want to overheat and therefore "disable" the GPU.

Thanks!

Comment: yes, you can. for sure.

Comment: I don't think so. You'll probably have a black screen with the GPU disabled.

Comment: Depending on your computer, you may have an Intel GPU along the Nvida GPU. In such case, you can instruct Ubuntu/X-Windows to use the Intel one instead of the Nvidia GPU. You may check http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: @Jaime I already tried this one, but for some reason after switching to Intel, I login and get a black screen. At the same time I believe to know that the Intel GPU is not on the CPU but on the Nvidia GPU, so the overheating is not solved. :S

Answer (score 2):

Let's separate 'gpu' from graphics card. With no video card, you have a 'headless' server. Login remotely from another system with SSH. I am not teasing, that is the answer.

IF you do have Intel graphics device on the motherboard, you can make it work, but reconfig of X11 software is needed. You don't tell what MOBO is, or if this is a discrete Nvidia card. I was guessing yes when I wrote next part.

I would remove Nvidia card entirely. In 1995, that would leave you with no graphics, generally everything was discrete. I have not seen a motherboard from Intel with no on board graphics in a long time. Do you have a second video jack on the back of the computer? If not, you are headless. If you change monitor to use other jack, maybe problem disappears.

I think you are wrong that Intel GPU is on Nvidia card. Intel almost certainly on MOBO.  But OS not finding it. (possible you have MOBO with on board Nvidia but no discrete card...)

Here is a way to tell if you have any hope. Run Alt-Ctl-F1 to get a VT. If that shows, Intel graphics card exists. It's not just the GPU that is needed, it is the larger set of graphics card functionality.

Then Alt-Ctl-F7 would go back to X11, if it were working. Before that, inspect the driver setup.

To make x11 WORK, you need change the x11 config. Settings for Nvidia will make the Intel graphics fail. In the VT, Move away the xorg.conf settings that Nvidia created. Then in cli run 'startx'. If gui starts, you have hope. More likely, go read /var/log/xsession.0 I expect you'll see what's wrong.

Why you need to fiddle settings: Even removing the Nvidia card won't help if X11 config is set to try Nvidia. There is no fallback after Nvidia settings has been run, it makes changes to /etc/X11.

OH, well. You need give details on hardware before I should work so hard guessing.

Comment: This. Pull the Nvidia card from the computer (as the fan has failed, I assume it's a discrete card). The Intel GPU is **part** of the CPU, e.g. on the same physical silicon as the CPU.

Comment: How can I see if my server is headless and cannot run any desktop? XRDP just won’t work though VNC does.